# Callback to Promises (nodes7)

Tags: node.js, promise, callback

I'm trying convert callback functions from nodeS7 API to promises.
There is the code with callback, whit work correctly:

```
var nodes7 = require('nodes7');  
var conn = new nodes7;
var doneReading = false;
var doneWriting = false;

var variables = { 
          TEST5: 'DB1,REAL4',
};

conn.initiateConnection({port: 102, host: '192.168.0.2', rack: 0, slot: 1}, connected);

function connected(err) {
    if (typeof(err) !== "undefined") {
        // We have an error.  Maybe the PLC is not reachable.
        console.log(err);
        process.exit();
    }
    conn.setTranslationCB(function(tag) {return variables[tag];}); 
    conn.addItems(['TEST5']);
    conn.readAllItems(valuesReady);
}

function valuesReady(anythingBad, values) {
    if (anythingBad) { console.log("SOMETHING WENT WRONG READING VALUES!!!!"); }
    console.log(values);   // return {'TEST5': 23.5}
    doneReading = true;
    if (doneWriting) { process.exit(); }
}
```

Now I'm trying do something like that:

```
var nodes7 = require('nodes7');  
var conn = new nodes7;

function readVal(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
         conn.initiateConnection({port: 102, host: '172.16.85.10', rack: 0, slot: 1}, resolve);
    })    
}
function connected() {
    conn.addItemsNow(['DB12,REAL140']);

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        conn.readAllItems(resolve);
      });
}
async function testAsync(dataToRead){
    try {
        await readVal();

        const readAll = await connected();
        console.log(readAll);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

}
testAsync();
```

Unfortunately, I still obtain readAll = false, but should be = {'DB12,REAL140': 23:45}.
Could you point me what is wrong?

Comment: You need to resolve a value. You are not returning any value for Resolve.

Comment: @Pronoy999 That's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readAllItems` callback - called `valuesReady` in your first code - accepts two parameters. The first is a possible error, and the second is the actual result:

```
conn.readAllItems(valuesReady);

// ...

function valuesReady(anythingBad, values) {
    if (anythingBad) { console.log("SOMETHING WENT WRONG READING VALUES!!!!"); }
    console.log(values);   // return {'TEST5': 23.5}
    doneReading = true;
    if (doneWriting) { process.exit(); }
}
```

But in your second code, the first parameter is being used by the `resolve` callback (and any subsequent arguments passed to `resolve` get ignored). So, as is, you're ending up with a resolve value of the `anythingBad`, which will be falsey under normal circumstances. That's why you're getting `false` at the moment.

Try rejecting with the first (error) parameter if it exists, and resolving with the second (resolved values) parameter otherwise:

```
function connected() {
    conn.addItemsNow(['DB12,REAL140']);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        conn.readAllItems((anythingBad, values) => {
            if (anythingBad) reject(anythingBad);
            else resolve(values);
        });
   });
}
```

You should also have the `readVal` reject in the case of an error (it will currently always resolve, which is probably not what you want):

```
function readVal(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         conn.initiateConnection({port: 102, host: '172.16.85.10', rack: 0, slot: 1}, (err) => {
             if (err) reject(err);
             else resolve();
         });
    })    
}
```

You can also use `util.promisify` to translate the callbacks to Promises automatically, but it looks a *bit* awkward since it's only operating on the `conn` (and needs to preserve its calling context, while not changing the `nodes7` prototype):

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

const initiateConnectionPromisified = promisify(conn.initiateConnection).bind(conn);
const readAllItemsPromisified = promisify(conn.readAllItems).bind(conn);

(async () => {
  await initiateConnectionPromisified({port: 102, host: '192.168.0.2', rack: 0, slot: 1});
  conn.setTranslationCB(function(tag) {return variables[tag];}); 
  conn.addItems(['TEST5']);
  await readAllItemsPromisified();
})();
```

Comment: Note that since both the functions are standard node callback style we can also use `util.promisify()` to convert them to promises = `const readAllItems = util.promisify(conn.readAllItems)`